# SVG Won't Vertically Center

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I've been desperately trying to find some way to center my logo svg within a `<div>` tag. I've scoured what felt like all of stack overflow, but to no avail. I hope someone... anyone can help me out with this!
Here is my code:

```css
.site-nav__list {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .nav-logo {
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        width: 3.7em;
        height: 3.7em;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .nav-logo svg {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .nav-logo svg g {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav__list">
          <li>
            <div class="nav-logo">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <g data-name="Layer 1">
                  <path d="M26.25 0v27.1H0a26.67 26.67 0 0 0 53.34 0V0H26.25z" />
                  <path d="M100 8.25a26.67 26.67 0 1 0-.41 37.3L81.14 27.11z" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Every solution I've found has not worked :/
And no, table cells and absolute positioning are stupid on a simple svg.

Comment: That's not it... the flexbox is for the rest of the navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several changes that you need to make to solve this problem:

1. The SVG has a `display:block` that will prevent some movement, change it to `inline-block` so things like `line-height` will affect it.
2. Add a `line-height` to `.nav-logo` of the same size as the `height` (3.7em) so the elements will be shown in the centered vertically.
3. Make the image align vertically to the middle of the line by adding a `vertical-align: middle`.
4. Remove the `width:100%` and `height:100%`, as you don't specify size for the SVG, it will automatically expand to the size of its container.

   With all those changes, the image is already centered... but it doesn't look like it. Why? Because there's one change left: the `viewBox`. Right now the SVG is two letters with a big blank space below. This happens because the viewBox, the canvas in which the image is drawn, is 100x100, but the "lowest" point of the image is at 53.34, leaving all the space underneath it blank.
5. So one last change: modify the viewBox so it limits the image to the content inside: the width is ok (100), but the height should be 53.34. After fixing that last part, the logo centers vertically:

```css
.site-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3.7em;
  height: 3.7em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 3.7em;
}

.nav-logo svg {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.nav-logo svg g {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav__list">
  <li>
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 53.34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g data-name="Layer 1">
          <path d="M26.25 0v27.1H0a26.67 26.67 0 0 0 53.34 0V0H26.25z" />
          <path d="M100 8.25a26.67 26.67 0 1 0-.41 37.3L81.14 27.11z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to limit the changes to a minimum, you would only need one simple step: translate the `g` tag to center it within the `svg`, so instead of leaving all the white space at the bottom, you put it above and underneath the letters.

You need to translate it vertically (100 - height of letters) / 2, as states previously, the height is 53.34, so the translation would need to be 23.33:

```css
.site-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3.7em;
  height: 3.7em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-logo svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.nav-logo svg g {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav__list">
  <li>
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <g data-name="Layer 1" transform="translate(0, 23.33)">
            <path d="M26.25 0v27.1H0a26.67 26.67 0 0 0 53.34 0V0H26.25z" />
            <path d="M100 8.25a26.67 26.67 0 1 0-.41 37.3L81.14 27.11z" />
          </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```